# Angular 2-way binding with multiple nested component

Tags: angular, typescript, two-way-binding, nested-controls

I'm new to angular and I want to content editing with angular 2-way binding to nested component. Here is the structure without 2-way binding.

parentModule.ts

```
this.contactList : Array[contact] =[];
```

parenModule.html

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of contactList">
        <app-contactCard [contact ]='contact '></app-contactCard>
</div>
```

nestedModule.ts

```
@Input() contact : contact;
```

nestedModule.Html

```
<div>{{this.contact.firstname}}- {{this.contact.firstname}}
```

Is it possible to add 2-way binding here and write to parent array of contacts from nested component?

Like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="this.contact.firstname"></input>
```

or is there any better approach to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly, but you can use @Output(), such as  <app-contactCard [contact]='contact' (onContactChange)="someFunction($event)">

Comment: I assume `nestedModule.ts` has a selector `app-contactCard`?

Comment: not work <input [(ngModel)]="contact.firstname"></input> ? (removing this). It's an object, so you're passing as argument the reference of the object